# What is the equivalent of Ruby's string.unpack('N') in Groovy?

Tags: ruby, groovy

How can I decode a string to 32 bit unsigned network byte order integer in Groovy?

In Ruby it can be done with [`"this is string".unpack('N')`](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/unpack)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get an equivalent of Ruby's `"string".unpack('N')` using Java NIO [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) class. Consider following example:

```groovy
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.nio.ByteOrder

final String str = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"

final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(str.bytes)
buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN)

final int result = buffer.getInt()

println result // 1819243109
```

And here is `"lorem ipsum dolor sit amet".unpack('N')` inside Ruby's REPL for a comparison - https://repl.it/repls/TeemingIndigoHypotenuse

Answer (score 1):

Building on @szymon-stepniak's answer, here's a way to write it as an `unpack` function via meta-programming:

```
import java.nio.*

String.metaClass.unpack {
    def s = delegate
    ByteBuffer.wrap(s.bytes).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).int
}

assert 1819243109 == "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet".unpack()
```